# How to merge rows in one using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query like this

[image]

What I want is showing one row and adding columns dynamically

Like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you need to use a pivot to accomplish this.

Comment: i think no, because i won't  transforrm rows values to column !! i don't know

Comment: How to know which cotation_prix to which col1, col2 or col3?

Comment: What methods have you tried so far? Have you tried PIVOT? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Where does the info 'Crane TDM' and 'Annulation' go? Do you just discard it? How do we decide which row goes into col2, col3, col4?

Comment: there is another column cotation_produit set to (0,1 or 2) in this case

Comment: each row has  cotation_produit then :col2 get the value(cotation_prix) of row that contain cotation_produit = 0,col3 when  cotation_produit = 1,col4 when cotation_produit = 2

Answer (score 1):

you must using pivot query.

```
SELECT cotation_study_uid, contation_label,[OMNIPAQUE 350*50ML] AS col1, [Crane TDM] AS col2, [Annulation produit] AS col3
(SELECT *
FROM yourtable)p
PIVOT (SUM(contation_prix) FOR cotation_label IN ('OMNIPAQUE 350*50ML', 'Crane TDM', 'Annulation produit'))
```

Comment: You would have to use a PIVOT-Statement written as dynamic SQL-Statement to specify the columns dynamically

Comment: but i can't fix cotation_label there are no just 'OMNIPAQUE 350*50ML', 'Crane TDM' ;.....there are lot of case